# Как брать куки сразу же после их установки?

Tags: php, массивы, cookie

Вот создаю я куку.

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID', 'id');
```

Но в массиве $_COOKIE она становится доступна только после перезагрузки. Но как получить ее сразу же?

Comment: никак. Только принудительно перезагрузить страницу. Например функцией `header('Location: ?');`

Answer (score 4):

> После передачи клиенту (через функцию `setcookie()`) cookie станут доступны через массив `$_COOKIE` при следующей загрузке страницы. Значения cookie также есть в `$_REQUEST`.

Если вам так важно сразу брать данные из массива `$_COOKIE`, а не из переменной, значение которой вы установили через `setcookie()`, то пишите так:

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID', $id, ...);
$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] = $id;
```

Comment: Мне нужно непосредственно в куки, а не только в массив.

Comment: Уже использую header

Comment: Привет всем. Как получить cookie при использовании VUE+NODE+SOKET.IO Проблема та же, устанавливаю cookie через заголовок с использованием SOKET.IO на клиенте получаю результат без перезагрузки страницы и не имею доступ к cookie (httpOnly)