# Как вывести значение куки в браузер без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, ajax, cookie

Добрый день!

Есть такой файл:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/php/ajax.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {inp:art, sum:sum, quant:quant},
    success: function(){
        $('.sum').text(sum);
        $('.goods_quantity').text(quant);
    }
})
```

И есть вот такой ('/php/ajax.php'):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['goods_quantity'])){
setcookie('goods_quantity', $_COOKIE['goods_quantity'] + $_GET['quant'], time()+3600*24*7, '/');
$gsq = $_COOKIE['goods_quantity'];
}
else{
    setcookie('goods_quantity', $_GET['quant'], time()+3600*24*7, '/');
    $gsq = $_COOKIE['goods_quantity'];
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['sum'])){
    setcookie('sum', $_COOKIE['sum'] + $_GET['sum'], time()+3600*24*7, '/');
    $sm = $_COOKIE['sum'];
}
else{
    setcookie('sum', $_GET['sum'], time()+3600*24*7, '/');
    $sm = $_COOKIE['sum'];
}
```

}

Нужно, чтобы данные отображались без перезагрузки страницы. Сейчас куки записываются, но значения их отображаются только после перезагрузки и с опозданием на один шаг.

Comment: Попробуйте джаваскриптом устанавливать [cookie](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)

Comment: Да уж интересно, что я недоделал в варианте с PHP

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683990/186083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie устанавливаются в браузере, а это значит, что [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php) ничего не устанавливает, а добавляет заголовок Set-Cookie в http запрос, в результате браузер видит этот заголовок и устанавливает куки.

На момент когда отработал `setcookie` в `$_COOKIE` ничего не попадает. Так как ещё ничего не установлено. А при повторном запросе отработает. Так как браузер обратно передал установленные cookie.

Если перейти по ссылке выше, то можно прочесть такую информацию по этому поводу:

> После передачи клиенту cookie станут доступны через массив $_COOKIE при следующей загрузке страницы. Значения cookie также есть в $_REQUEST.