# Почему куки не корректно работают при их установке через ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cookie

Мне нужно устанавливать куки с помощью ajax.
При нажатии на ссылку, скрипт в html коде отправляет данные php скрипту.
И возвращает ответ в result_area.

Что должен делать этот код. При нажатии на ссылку будет дважды вызван скрипт actions.php который будет изменять куки cookie_string.
Итого в куки должно быть another_cookieanother_cookie.

При первом нажатии на ссылку - мы ничего не увидим на странице.
Если мы посмотрим в браузер->куки->cookie_string там будет another_cookie.

При втором нажатии на ссылку - мы увидим на странице another_cookie.
Если мы посмотрим в браузер->куки->cookie_string там будет another_cookieanother_cookie.

При третьем нажатии на ссылку - мы увидим на странице another_cookieanother_cookie.
Если мы посмотрим в браузер->куки->cookie_string там будет another_cookieanother_cookieanother_cookie.
и т.д.

Как вы видите - вывод кук не соответствует действительности.
Как будто выводится предыдущий результат (на "шаг назад").
Почему куки не корректно  работают при их установке через ajax?
И как мне корректно их устанавливать через ajax в данном случае?

HTML

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#input_area').on('click', '.cookie_link', function(){

/*Первый вызов*/
$.ajax({
url: 'actions.php?set_my_cookie&id='+this.id,
success: function(data){$('#result_area').html(data);}
});

/*Второй вызов*/
$.ajax({
url: 'actions.php?set_my_cookie&id='+this.id,
success: function(data){$('#result_area').html(data);}
});


return false;
});
});
</script>


<div id="input_area">
<a href="#" class="cookie_link" id="another_cookie">Link</a>
</div>

<div id="result_area">

</div>
```

PHP

```
//Принимаемые данные
$id=$_GET['id'];

//Вызов функции
if (isset($_GET['set_my_cookie']))
{
$cookie_string=$_COOKIE['cookie_string'];
$cookie_string=$cookie_string.$id;
setcookie('cookie_string', $cookie_string, time()+31536000,"/");
echo $_COOKIE['cookie_string'];
}
```

Comment: Cookie не работают после вывода любой информации на страницу. Уже 100 раз об этом писали. Почитайте о setcookie в документации php

Comment: 1. Если вы их задаете по https протоколу - то и получить вы их сможете только при https, аналогично и с http.

Comment: KAGG Design а что я делаю не так?
Ведь после, а не перед. А я вызываю их в конце. Перед ними нет никакого вывода. Я вывожу (возвращаю) только их.

Comment: Почему тут многих тянет забивать болты молотком? Неужели нельзя посмотреть примеры или прочитать документацию, и посмотреть как принято решать аналогичную задачу вместо того чтобы городить огород? Учитесь пользоваться поисковыми системами, она спасут вам больше нервных клеток и предотвратят новый 2000 год в трехтысячном.

Comment: Daniel Protopopov - конструктив?
Я делаю что -то совсем неприемлемое?
Моя задача проста - пользователь щелкнул по ссылке, я запомнил что он щелкнул. Ну и вывел ему информацию.

Я хочу хранить эту информацию в куках.
Читаю куки, пишу куки, вывожу куки.

Но вывод не совпадает с реальным значением.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683990/186083