# Как получить cookie при использовании VUE+NODE+SOKET.IO

Tags: node.js, vue.js, сокет

Всем привет, моя проблема изложена [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683976/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/683990#683990) она по теме php, в комментариях к вопросу написал, еще раз дублирую:

Как получить cookie при использовании VUE+NODE+SOKET.IO Проблема та же, устанавливаю cookie через заголовок с использованием SOKET.IO на клиенте получаю результат без перезагрузки страницы и при отправке с той же страницы данные на сервер не имею доступ к cookie (httpOnly)

так ставлю заголовок

```
           io.engine.on("headers", (headers, request) => {
                headers["set-cookie"] = Cookies.serialize(
                    "refreh_token",
                    authentication.refresh_token,
                    {
                        httpOnly: true,
                        maxAge: 60*60*24*20,
                        path: '/',
                        sameSite: "lax"
                    } );
            });
```

после получения на клиенте вех токенов jwt получаю и записываю, а вот при попытке получит рефрешь из   cookie (httpOnly) на сервере не могу, только после обновления страницы и отправке данных во vue (без перезагрузки)могу это сделать

Answer (score 0):

@submit.**prevent** - вот что не позволяло подгрузить cookie во vue на клиенте